# calculate new price_unit in sale order line

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I have created a new custom module to include width and lenght of a product as attributes with custom values, and I need to update the price_unit of the sales order line with the current unit price multiplied by the (lenght*witdh) value, so I can have the price per surface unit in the product card, and the price per total surface in the sales order line.
I use the product configurator and this is my code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


# import pymsgbox

class aurea_calculated_field_line(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
    field_superficie = fields.Float('Superficie')
    field_alto = fields.Integer('Alto')
    field_ancho = fields.Integer('Ancho')

    @api.onchange('field_alto', 'field_ancho', 'product_uom_qty', 'quantity')
    def _value_pc5(self):
        for record in self:
            record.field_superficie = record.field_ancho * record.field_alto
            self.price_unit = float(self.field_superficie) * self.product_id.lst_price

    @api.onchange('product_id')
    def _value_pc4(self):
        if not self.product_custom_attribute_value_ids and not self.product_no_variant_attribute_value_ids:
            return ""
        for pacv in self.product_custom_attribute_value_ids:
            if pacv.custom_product_template_attribute_value_id.display_name == 'Largo: Largo':
                self.field_alto = pacv.custom_value
            if pacv.custom_product_template_attribute_value_id.display_name == 'Ancho: Ancho':
                self.field_ancho = pacv.custom_value
```

It works fine, but the problem is when I change the product quantity the unit price is reset to the product pricelist price.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't you update quantity instead of unit_price? Your Unit of Measure (UoM) is something like m², so changing width and length changes how many units you have, not its price.

Comment: It's the last option, because if I update the quantity the quotation data will be a little bit confusing. The item is for example a promotional canvas, they have a price per cm2, so depending of the size of the canvas, the sistem should calculate the final price. If my canvas has a pr1ce of 0,10 euros/cm2, and it measures 50x100cm=5000cm2, the final price should be 500 euros per canvas, if the customer demands 2 or 3 or whatever quantity, the unit price is the same.

Comment: The problem is that if I update the quantity, my new quantity should be 50x100xquantity of items, so if the customer demans 2 canvas, the quantity will be 50x100x2=10.000, if they demand 3, then 15.000, but the customer buy promotional canvas not cm2

Comment: You've created new fields anyway to your order line. What if you use those fields to calculate row total sum. Then your unit price would be $/m², quantity how many Canvas and each line have unique size of the canvas. Total price of the line would be unit_price * qty * height* width.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at this a bit. I didn't reproduce the problem but here is something you probably can work with.

In Odoo13 source code in file `addons/sale/models/sale.py` on line 1614 is a method which causes behavior you have problem with:

```
    @api.onchange('product_uom', 'product_uom_qty')
    def product_uom_change(self):
        if not self.product_uom or not self.product_id:
            self.price_unit = 0.0
            return
        if self.order_id.pricelist_id and self.order_id.partner_id:
            product = self.product_id.with_context(
                lang=self.order_id.partner_id.lang,
                partner=self.order_id.partner_id,
                quantity=self.product_uom_qty,
                date=self.order_id.date_order,
                pricelist=self.order_id.pricelist_id.id,
                uom=self.product_uom.id,
                fiscal_position=self.env.context.get('fiscal_position')
            )
            self.price_unit = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price_company(self._get_display_price(product), product.taxes_id, self.tax_id, self.company_id)
```

This re-calculates unit price when product quantity is changed. You'd have to overwrite this method in your code. Easiest way would be add this to your `aurea_calculated_field_line`-class.

```
def product_uom_change(self):
    return
```

But this needs a lot of testing to make sure that some other feature does not break because of this.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you very much

Comment: Happy to hear if that helps. If you think that is correct answer, you could accept it as an answer for your question. That is the way how SO reputation point system works. And everyone wants their virtual petting :)